# How to implement a single item for a linked list class?

Tags: c++, class

I'm extremely new to C++, so I wanted to get some help on a homework problem that I've been working on for the past few hours. The criteria of the problem is this:

> In the problems below, we will be implementing a list of "items."  In this problem, we will create an Item class for this purpose.
>
> To make things a little interesting, we will have two components to our Item: (1) an integer key and (2) a literal string value.
>
> Your class must include:
>
> [2.5 pts] Private member variables for the key (int) and value (const char *).  Don't allocate space for the string -- just keep a pointer.
>
> [2.5 pts] A public constructor that initializes the key and value.  Again, don't copy the string that is passed in -- just save the pointer.
>
> [2.5 pts] Public methods to read the key and value -- e.g., getKey(), getValue().
>
> [2.5 pts] A public copy constructor.

I'm extremely confused on how to implement the third and the fourth bullet points. I've attached my code below, if any of you guys could tell me what I'm doing wrong and how to go about implementing these parts. The reason I'm confused is because I'm not exactly sure what they are designed to do.

```
class Item {
    Private:
        int key;
        const char* point;
    Public:
        Item(int key, char* point); //I'm not sure when to put brackets after a constructor? The examples given are usually pretty vague.
        getKey(key); //What do these do? We never went over these in class? What is the point?
        getValue(point);
        Item(const Item &new) {
            key = new.key;
            value = new.imaginary;
        }
};
```

Comment: I would avoid naming variables `new`.

Comment: Can you be a little more specific about what your question is? "I don't know what to do" is a little vague. Are you asking, "How do I implement a copy constructor?", if so , did you google it up? It's find if you don't understand it, but narrow things down a little.

Comment: `getKey(key);` and `getValue(point);` are not correct signatures.

Comment: As for the get methods. Well, they want to get. If you don't understand their point, perhaps we need to revist public, private, protected, scope. Do you understand the difference between public and private? The Get methods are there as part of a public interface to expose the private data. They will need to return the type of that data. For example: int GetKey() const;

Comment: The point of getters (getKey/Value) is to have a **public** member function that returns the value of a **private** member.

Comment: @others I wonder if the instructor does not want the c-string copied in the copy constructor, since the constructors don't copy it either. What an odd and terrible way to teach people. Let's purposely make code that doesn't take ownership of its data...

Answer (score 2):

I think you want something like this:

```
int getKey() const { return key; }
```

Your copy constructor would be something like this:

```
Item(const Item &other) : key(other.key), value(other.value) { }
```

And I'm not sure what compilers, if any, will accept "Private:" and "Public:" with the capital "P".  Also, as drescherjm mentioned, "new" shouldn't be used as a variable name.  It is a C++ operator.

Answer (score 1):

You need to implement the `int Item::getKey() const` and the `const char* Item::getValue() const` functions. Notice how it has a parameter type of `void` because you aren't going to pass anything to it, and it has a return type of `int` or `const char*` depending on which one you are going to get.

```
int getKey() const {
    return key;
}
```

It is literally that simple. As Christopher PiszAll stated below, the `const` keyword indicates that no members were changed by the function. All that the function is going to do is return the internal member `key`. Now do the same for `value`.

However, "getters" are avoided by experienced programmers because it breaks encapsulation. The best programmers create functions that manipulate their members. Since this is homework though, you should do as your instructor wishes.

And, as commenters mentioned, don't ever use `new` as a parameter name. That is a reserved keyword for allocating new memory.

Comment: This is missing const correctness. int getKey() const {

Comment: Fixed! Sorry for my initial misunderstanding :-)

Answer (score -1):

The third point is pretty straightforwards, you want methods that can read the key and value. Depending on what they want want exactly returned, you should be able to say, have some method getKey that roughly does:

```
int Item::getKey() {
    return key;
}
```

It reads the key and returns it. Same idea with the getValue() method.

As for the copy constructor, the idea is pretty simple - it copies the values of another item into the new item.

```
Item(const Item &i) { //Don't call it "new" 
        key = i.getKey()
        value = i.getValue();
}
```

Comment: A copy constructor is a part of the class, hence it can read the private members directly.

Comment: Missing const correctness. int Item::getKey() const {

Comment: @ChristopherPisz Can you clearly explain why you need it to be const? Am I accidentally creating UB?

Comment: Copy constructor doesn't need to use the get methods, it can just read the data directly. Also, have you considered whether or not the string needs to be copied? While it seems the instructor in the OP wants to purposely make this class do bad things, I'd at least mention it.

Comment: @ Daniel It's just a nitpick. Getters in C++ that do not change the member data should be const. The signature int Item::getKey() const makes a promise that it will not change Item in any way. If you did not use that signature, you might have a hard time calling getKey on a const Item

Comment: What is the point of having a function like "getkey" or "getvalue" when I can just pass the values I need for the functions through the constructor? My professor has written smaller C++ programs that never needed this in order to pass values into the functions from the objects they were originally declared with.

Comment: @JohnHarrison If you want other classes to have access to private members, this is one way to do so.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz are you not also going to lambast the teacher for not teaching them to use std::string instead of primitive arrays? Gotta make sure the class doesn't do bad things ;)

Comment: @Daniel RAII, ownership, and lifetime, are pretty fundamental both in academic exercises and in the real world.. c-string vs std::string is a debate I don't press in an academic setting. Students need to understand c-string. They will run into it on the job.

Comment: @ChristopherPisz what about the Rule of three? (or five, YMMV). After all, they are explicitly defining the copy constructor ...

Comment: @Daniel Feel free to message me if you'd like to talk more. I'd rather not confuse new people.